# Put list in a special format

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-manipulation

I am having problems with a list that I want to put in a special format and I would like you to help me, the list I have is the following:

```
dts={{Polygon[{{11/2, 0}, {37/8, 5/8}, {29/8, -(5/8)}}], 
  1, {11/2, 0}}, {Polygon[{{37/8, 5/8}, {15/4, 5/4}, {29/8, -(5/8)}}],
   2, {37/8, 5/
   8}}, {Polygon[{{29/8, -(5/8)}, {7/2, -(5/2)}, {9/2, -(5/4)}}], 
  3, {29/8, -(5/
    8)}}, {Polygon[{{9/2, -(5/4)}, {11/2, 0}, {29/8, -(5/8)}}], 
  4, {9/2, -(5/4)}}, {Polygon[{{11/2, 0}, {13/2, 5/4}, {45/8, 15/8}}],
   5, {11/2, 0}}, {Polygon[{{13/2, 5/4}, {15/2, 5/2}, {45/8, 15/8}}], 
  6, {13/2, 5/4}}, {Polygon[{{45/8, 15/8}, {15/4, 5/4}, {37/8, 5/8}}],
   7, {45/8, 15/8}}, {Polygon[{{37/8, 5/8}, {11/2, 0}, {45/8, 15/8}}],
   8, {37/8, 5/8}}, {Polygon[{{7/4, -(5/4)}, {11/4, 0}, {15/8, 5/8}}],
   9, {7/4, -(5/4)}}, {Polygon[{{11/4, 0}, {15/4, 5/4}, {15/8, 5/8}}],
   10, {11/4, 0}}, {Polygon[{{15/8, 5/8}, {0, 0}, {7/8, -(5/8)}}], 
  11, {15/8, 5/
   8}}, {Polygon[{{7/8, -(5/8)}, {7/4, -(5/4)}, {15/8, 5/8}}], 
  12, {7/8, -(5/
    8)}}, {Polygon[{{7/4, -(5/4)}, {21/8, -(15/8)}, {29/8, -(5/8)}}], 
  13, {7/4, -(5/
    4)}}, {Polygon[{{21/8, -(15/8)}, {7/2, -(5/2)}, {29/8, -(5/8)}}], 
  14, {21/8, -(15/
    8)}}, {Polygon[{{29/8, -(5/8)}, {15/4, 5/4}, {11/4, 0}}], 
  15, {29/8, -(5/
    8)}}, {Polygon[{{11/4, 0}, {7/4, -(5/4)}, {29/8, -(5/8)}}], 
  16, {11/4, 
   0}}, {Polygon[{{21/4, -(15/4)}, {25/4, -(5/2)}, {43/8, -(15/8)}}], 
  17, {21/4, -(15/
    4)}}, {Polygon[{{25/4, -(5/2)}, {29/4, -(5/4)}, {43/8, -(15/8)}}],
   18, {25/4, -(5/
    2)}}, {Polygon[{{43/8, -(15/8)}, {7/2, -(5/2)}, {35/8, -(25/8)}}],
   19, {43/8, -(15/
    8)}}, {Polygon[{{35/8, -(25/8)}, {21/4, -(15/4)}, {43/
     8, -(15/8)}}], 
  20, {35/8, -(25/
    8)}}, {Polygon[{{21/4, -(15/4)}, {49/8, -(35/8)}, {57/
     8, -(25/8)}}], 
  21, {21/4, -(15/
    4)}}, {Polygon[{{49/8, -(35/8)}, {7, -5}, {57/8, -(25/8)}}], 
  22, {49/8, -(35/
    8)}}, {Polygon[{{57/8, -(25/8)}, {29/4, -(5/4)}, {25/4, -(5/2)}}],
   23, {57/8, -(25/
    8)}}, {Polygon[{{25/4, -(5/2)}, {21/4, -(15/4)}, {57/
     8, -(25/8)}}], 
  24, {25/4, -(5/
    2)}}, {Polygon[{{11/2, 0}, {51/8, -(5/8)}, {59/8, 5/8}}], 
  25, {11/2, 
   0}}, {Polygon[{{51/8, -(5/8)}, {29/4, -(5/4)}, {59/8, 5/8}}], 
  26, {51/8, -(5/
    8)}}, {Polygon[{{59/8, 5/8}, {15/2, 5/2}, {13/2, 5/4}}], 
  27, {59/8, 5/8}}, {Polygon[{{13/2, 5/4}, {11/2, 0}, {59/8, 5/8}}], 
  28, {13/2, 5/
   4}}, {Polygon[{{11/2, 0}, {9/2, -(5/4)}, {43/8, -(15/8)}}], 
  29, {11/2, 
   0}}, {Polygon[{{9/2, -(5/4)}, {7/2, -(5/2)}, {43/8, -(15/8)}}], 
  30, {9/2, -(5/
    4)}}, {Polygon[{{43/8, -(15/8)}, {29/4, -(5/4)}, {51/8, -(5/8)}}],
   31, {43/8, -(15/
    8)}}, {Polygon[{{51/8, -(5/8)}, {11/2, 0}, {43/8, -(15/8)}}], 
  32, {51/8, -(5/
    8)}}, {Polygon[{{23/4, 15/4}, {27/4, 5}, {47/8, 45/8}}], 
  33, {23/4, 15/
   4}}, {Polygon[{{27/4, 5}, {31/4, 25/4}, {47/8, 45/8}}], 
  34, {27/4, 5}}, {Polygon[{{47/8, 45/8}, {4, 5}, {39/8, 35/8}}], 
  35, {47/8, 45/
   8}}, {Polygon[{{39/8, 35/8}, {23/4, 15/4}, {47/8, 45/8}}], 
  36, {39/8, 35/
   8}}, {Polygon[{{23/4, 15/4}, {53/8, 25/8}, {61/8, 35/8}}], 
  37, {23/4, 15/
   4}}, {Polygon[{{53/8, 25/8}, {15/2, 5/2}, {61/8, 35/8}}], 
  38, {53/8, 25/
   8}}, {Polygon[{{61/8, 35/8}, {31/4, 25/4}, {27/4, 5}}], 
  39, {61/8, 35/
   8}}, {Polygon[{{27/4, 5}, {23/4, 15/4}, {61/8, 35/8}}], 
  40, {27/4, 5}}, {Polygon[{{6, 15/2}, {55/8, 55/8}, {63/8, 65/8}}], 
  41, {6, 15/
   2}}, {Polygon[{{55/8, 55/8}, {31/4, 25/4}, {63/8, 65/8}}], 
  42, {55/8, 55/8}}, {Polygon[{{63/8, 65/8}, {8, 10}, {7, 35/4}}], 
  43, {63/8, 65/8}}, {Polygon[{{7, 35/4}, {6, 15/2}, {63/8, 65/8}}], 
  44, {7, 35/4}}, {Polygon[{{6, 15/2}, {5, 25/4}, {47/8, 45/8}}], 
  45, {6, 15/2}}, {Polygon[{{5, 25/4}, {4, 5}, {47/8, 45/8}}], 
  46, {5, 25/
   4}}, {Polygon[{{47/8, 45/8}, {31/4, 25/4}, {55/8, 55/8}}], 
  47, {47/8, 45/
   8}}, {Polygon[{{55/8, 55/8}, {6, 15/2}, {47/8, 45/8}}], 
  48, {55/8, 55/8}}, {Polygon[{{2, 5/2}, {23/8, 15/8}, {31/8, 25/8}}],
   49, {2, 5/2}}, {Polygon[{{23/8, 15/8}, {15/4, 5/4}, {31/8, 25/8}}],
   50, {23/8, 15/8}}, {Polygon[{{31/8, 25/8}, {4, 5}, {3, 15/4}}], 
  51, {31/8, 25/8}}, {Polygon[{{3, 15/4}, {2, 5/2}, {31/8, 25/8}}], 
  52, {3, 15/4}}, {Polygon[{{2, 5/2}, {1, 5/4}, {15/8, 5/8}}], 
  53, {2, 5/2}}, {Polygon[{{1, 5/4}, {0, 0}, {15/8, 5/8}}], 
  54, {1, 5/4}}, {Polygon[{{15/8, 5/8}, {15/4, 5/4}, {23/8, 15/8}}], 
  55, {15/8, 5/8}}, {Polygon[{{23/8, 15/8}, {2, 5/2}, {15/8, 5/8}}], 
  56, {23/8, 15/
   8}}, {Polygon[{{23/4, 15/4}, {19/4, 5/2}, {45/8, 15/8}}], 
  57, {23/4, 15/
   4}}, {Polygon[{{19/4, 5/2}, {15/4, 5/4}, {45/8, 15/8}}], 
  58, {19/4, 5/
   2}}, {Polygon[{{45/8, 15/8}, {15/2, 5/2}, {53/8, 25/8}}], 
  59, {45/8, 15/
   8}}, {Polygon[{{53/8, 25/8}, {23/4, 15/4}, {45/8, 15/8}}], 
  60, {53/8, 25/
   8}}, {Polygon[{{23/4, 15/4}, {39/8, 35/8}, {31/8, 25/8}}], 
  61, {23/4, 15/4}}, {Polygon[{{39/8, 35/8}, {4, 5}, {31/8, 25/8}}], 
  62, {39/8, 35/
   8}}, {Polygon[{{31/8, 25/8}, {15/4, 5/4}, {19/4, 5/2}}], 
  63, {31/8, 25/
   8}}, {Polygon[{{19/4, 5/2}, {23/4, 15/4}, {31/8, 25/8}}], 
  64, {19/4, 5/2}}};
```

and I want it this way:

```
dts={{Polygon[{{11/2, 0}, {37/8, 5/8}, {29/8, -(5/8)}}], 
 Text[1, {11/2, 0}]}, {Polygon[{{37/8, 5/8}, {15/4, 5/4}, {29/8, -(5/8)}}],
  Text[ 2, {37/8, 5/
   8}]}, {Polygon[{{29/8, -(5/8)}, {7/2, -(5/2)}, {9/2, -(5/4)}}], 
 Text[3, {29/8, -(5/
    8)}]},...{Polygon[{{19/4, 5/2}, {23/4, 15/4}, {31/8, 25/8}}], 
  Text[64, {19/4, 5/2}]}};
```

I tried with `Apply`, `Map` and finally with `MapAt` without success,I thought I would use `Inner` and `Outer` but I did not get the expected result, it is for this reason that I ask for your help in order to solve my problem, this was my last attempt using `MapAt` and see what I got

```
MapAt[Text, #, {{2}, {3}}] & /@ dts
```

as you will see is not how I need it, I hope you can help me. I do not know which command to use here, thanks in advance.

Comment: A slight variation on other answers: `dts /. {x_, y_, z_} :> {x, Text[y, z]}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
dts2 = {#, Text[##2]} & @@@ dts;

Short[dts2, 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Your solution is how I try to solve it without success, thank you for showing me how to do it, it's what I was looking for, thank you for helping me

Comment: @user1935664, glad to be of help. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 4):

Let

```
dts = {{Polygon[{{11/2, 0}, {37/8, 5/8}, {29/8, -(5/8)}}], 1, {11/2, 0}},
      {Polygon[{{37/8, 5/8}, {15/4, 5/4}, {29/8, -(5/8)}}], 2, {37/8, 5/8}}};
```

then

```
Cases[dts, {Polygon[x_], y_, z_} :> {Polygon[x], Text[y, z]}]
```

> {{Polygon[{{11/2, 0}, {37/8, 5/8}, {29/8, -(5/8)}}], 
>     Text[1, {11/2, 
>       0}]}, {Polygon[{{37/8, 5/8}, {15/4, 5/4}, {29/8, -(5/8)}}], 
>     Text[2, {37/8, 5/8}]}}

---

And for completeness, to take into account [the comment of tomd above:](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139854/put-list-in-a-special-format#comment377577_139854)

```
dts /. {x_, y_, z_} :> {x, Text[y, z]}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I learned more about using the Cases command, this command had not taken into account.